# $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ implies integral $f_n$ converges to integral $f$

Tags: measure-theory, limits, integration, convergence-divergence

Let  $\lambda(E)< \infty$ and $f_n$ be measurable and continuous (on $E$) for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

If $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ (continuous on $E$) for all $x\in E$, then $\int_Ef_n d\lambda$ converges to $\int_Ef d\lambda$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is false. Take $f_n(x)=(n+1)x^n$ on $(0,1)$ whose pointwise limit is $0$ for a counterexample. Then see [Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) for a true and powerful result along these lines.

Related: Note that if $E$ is compact and if $(f_n)$ is a monotone sequence of continuous functions on $E$ which converges pointwise to a continuous function $f$ on $E$, then [Dini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) says that the convergence is uniform. In this case, we easily get $\lim \int_E f_n=\int_Ef$ without Lebesgue DCT.

Comment: In that case, $f$ is not continuous on $E$. In the limit as $n\to \infty$, $f_n(x)=0$ for $x<1$ but $f_n(1)\to \infty$.

Comment: @GlenO If you read carefully, $E=(0,1)$ and $f=0$ on $E$. I purposedly removed $1$.

Comment: Might you have an example where the integral is not finite?

Comment: @HaikalYeo Do you mean: where the measure space has infinite measure?

Comment: @julien The measure space can be finite or infinite. I'm trying to look for a similar counterexample but with the case where $\int f=\lim\int f_n=\infty$.

Comment: @HaikalYeo You mean $\int f\neq \lim\int f_n=+\infty$. Otherwise, it is not a counterexample. Then it is very easy to adapt the example above. Take $f_n(x)=n(n+1)x^n$ on $(0,1)$.